# Background image being split up

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a `background image` to go behind a contact form in `BetterCMS` but for some reason, the `background image` is only being applied to the `text` elements of my `form`as per below;

[image]

I have absolutey no idea why this is happening, I have set the `z-index` to `999` but it still doesn't go solid!

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated!

HTML

```
    <div class="pull-right">
<div class ="formcontainer">
<form>

first name <br>

<input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name <br>

<input type="text" name="lastname"><br>

Email <br>

<input type="text" name="email"><br>

Phone Number <br>

<input type="text" name="PhoneNumber"><br>

</form>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.formcontainer
{
    background-image:url("http://localhost:53514/uploads/image/7d595f93f6b343d1aeab5958bc844f91/bikes_1.png");
     z-index:9999;
}
```

Comment: without looking at the code, I would think its being applied to the input part

Comment: your form elements are blocking it.

Comment: how would i get around that, if i want the picture in the background?

Comment: @Captain_Custard answer posted.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the form elements to transparent:

```css
body {
   background-color: red;
}

input {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

By default they have a default background color that *may* come from the OS.